# how to pass a variable to state as a index key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, ecmascript-6

I wanna pass a variable in my state. i am using setState({type: value}) 
but react dosent accept my first variable (type).

```
updateSwitch(type, value) {

    this.setState({
        type: value
    })

}
```

hear in my code, "type" is State's index key. i need this to my dynamic variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use es6 computed property

```
updateSwitch(type, value) {

this.setState({
    [type]: value
})
```

}

Read more about it here : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [**computed property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation).

```
updateSwitch(type, value) {

    this.setState({
        [type]: value
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do following:

```
this.setState({
    [type]: value
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dynamic property name (also known as [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)):

```
updateSwitch(type, value) {
    this.setState({
        [type]: value
    });
}
```